# android- OnStart never called when files come from the Gallery

Tags: android

what am i doing wrong here or is this a feature.

My `Activity` is set up in the manifest to be recipients for images.
I select an image in the Android `Gallery` and press share.
My activity start and i do stuff with the image.

Now, when long-press Home button and open my mail
and then go back to my `Activity` i was expecting the
`OnStart()` to be called.
It is not called.
I place breakpoints on other places and they work.

This `Activity` does not have a `.LAUNCHER` setup
an can only be accessed this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be calling onResume check that. It essentially means that your activity is still in the memory for the second time.

Comment: It does not call OnResume(). it does not sound like android lifecycle behavior. Really need to update a ListView if needed. Question is how to do that.

Comment: it is the correct behavior, unless you activity is destroyed or stopped, it would not call onStart. Right now another activity merely comes in front and your activity still stays in the activity stack.